# Where can I learn more about Lambda Expressions?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I have finally finished reading Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework **Chapter 3: Pre-requisites** but still a little confused about lambda expressions.

Where could I watch a video on it or read a guide about Lambda expressions with diagrams and pictures to help me better visualize it?

/* Thanks */

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Video's:

[What is LINQ? Can you explain it with suitable example?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQYjCze_b8s)

[How Do I: Get Started with LINQ](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZLdkSNX1U08)

[Using Linq](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B0gD0NqbGHk)

Over an above the videos some other great resources that explains Lambda Expressions, that I would recommend are the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) and the [Hooked on Linq](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/) website. The is also the best book I ever read on linq called [LINQ to Objects Using C# 4.0](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQBook.ashx) which is authored by the man who started the Hooked on Linq website.

Answer (score 2):

TekPub always does a great job with their instructional videos. If videos are your thing, I strongly encourage you to [subscribe](http://tekpub.com/pricing) to their service so you can view all the videos they offer. BUT the one you are looking for is actually provided FREE. They did a 5-part series on programming concepts and there's an entire episode devoted to Lambdas.. check it out:

http://tekpub.com/view/concepts/2